# Change element:after content depending on textContent of seperate element using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to inherit the `textContent` of a seperate `span` element to the `content` of an `:after` style using Vanilla JavaScript.

As seen below in HTML, the `span` with `className` *span-class*, is the element that I want to extract the `textContent` from. The div with `className` *sample*, is the `parent` of the `div` with `className` *random* (which houses *span-class*), and the `p` element for which I want to apply an `:after` style, with an inherited `content:" ";`.

These elements are repeated throughout the website with the same `className`, and hence require an Array as shown below in the **Desired Outcome**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sample">
 <div class="random">
  <span class="span-class">example</span>
 </div>
 <p class="p-text">some random text, some random text, some random text</p>
</div>


<div class="sample">
 <div class="random">
  <span class="span-class">example2</span>
 </div>
 <p class="p-text">some random text, some random text, some random text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.p-text:after{
  content: "text I want to be dynamic";
}
```

**Desired Outcome:**

NOTE: *I understand that `pText:after.content` does not work, however it best characterizes what I want to achieve*

```
var sample = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".sample"));

sample.forEach(function(smpl) {

var textContent = smpl.querySelector(".span-class").textContent;
var pText = smpl.querySelector(".p-text");

  if (textContent === "example") {
    pText:after.content = "example";
   } else if (textContent === "example2") {
    pText:after.content = "example2";
   }
 })
```

ALSO NOTE: *Creating another `span` element and placing it at the end of the `textContent` of `.p-text`, although a solution, is not an option*.

Thanks in advance for any solutions!

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5734583/2417602

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML Before**

```
<div class="sample">
  <div class="random">
    <span class="span-class">example</span>
  </div>
  <p class="p-text">some random text, some random text, some random text</p>
</div>

<div class="sample">
  <div class="random">
    <span class="span-class">example2</span>
  </div>
  <p class="p-text">some random text, some random text, some random text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.p-text:after{
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

Targeting attribute `data-content` within the `p` element allows for its manipulation using `el.dataset.content = "";`, as shown below using JavaScript.

Note, if an element does not already contain attribute `data-content`, the JavaScript below will automatically create one and implement the desired changes accordingly.

**JavaScript**

```
var sample = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".sample"));

sample.forEach(function(smpl) {

    var textContent = smpl.querySelector(".span-class").textContent;
    var pText = smpl.querySelector(".p-text");
    if (textContent === "example") {
      pText.dataset.content = "example";
    } else if (textContent === "example2") {
      pText.dataset.content = "example2";
    }
})
```

**Outcome After JS/CSS**

```
<div class="sample">
  <div class="random">
    <span class="span-class">example</span>
  </div>
  <p class="p-text" data-content="example">
    some random text, some random text, some random text.
    ::after
  </p>
</div>

<div class="sample">
  <div class="random">
    <span class="span-class">example2</span>
  </div>
  <p class="p-text" data-content="example2">
    some random text, some random text, some random text.
    ::after
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get get all the elements with this class `p-text` and from here get the it's parent and use querySelector to get the specific child node. Then get it's content and update the text content of the `.p-text` element

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.p-text').forEach(function(item) {
  let m = item.parentNode.querySelector('.span-class').textContent;
  let ItemContent = item.textContent + ' ' + m;
  item.innerHTML = ItemContent
})
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  <div class="random">
    <span class="span-class">example</span>
  </div>
  <p class="p-text">some random text, some random text, some random text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css variables in modern browsers.

```
.p-text:after{
  content: var(--p-text-content, "");
  color: green;
}
```

Like this :

```js
var sample = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".sample"));

sample.forEach(function(smpl) {

 var textContent = smpl.querySelector(".span-class").textContent;
 var pText = smpl.querySelector(".p-text");

 pText.style.setProperty("--p-text-content", `'${textContent}'`);
})
```

```css
.p-text:after{
  content: var(--p-text-content, "");
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
 <div class="random">
  <span class="span-class">example</span>
 </div>
 <p class="p-text">some random text, some random text, some random text</p>
</div>
```